# Google Analytics User Timings API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using User Timing API for recording performance of my application. It say's in the documentation:

"Google Analytics will sample timing hits during processing in order to ensure an equitable distribution of system resources for this feature.
The rate at which timing hits are sampled is determined by the total number of pageview hits received during the previous day for the property. The following table outlines how the timing sampling rate is determined"

If I look at my [previous day's pageview hits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIFj2.png)(I believe pageviews and pageview hits are same which we get from Audience -> Overview) it is 47,101 for March 1st. If we calculate 10% of 47,101 = 4710.1. I can't see 4710 user timing hits. It only shows [825 on March 2nd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcw1A.png). But we have way more user timing hits than 826. How do I validate this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set batch=True to require all the data. Also, you can get data day by day by setting walk=true this results in unsampled data.

```html
ga$getData(xxx,
start.date = "", 
end.date = "",
metrics = "", 
dimensions = "", 
sort = "", 
filters = "", 
segment = "",
,batch = TRUE, walk = TRUE
)
```